# Drupal 7 to drupal 7 migration

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-7, migration, drupal-hooks

I want to migrate drupal 7 to drupal 7. I used migrate module and drupal to drupal migrate module, but in total I can able migrate only 600 records among 1000 records. 400 records are failed. I don't know why it gets failed.

If I Processed 57 record among them 7 will failed. Then
Processed 57(50 created, 0 updated, 7 failed, 0 ignored). When I check the report status I am getting the node ids. Those node id are there in origin site but it is not get migrated to new site. How I can migrate those failed node id? Is there any solution?

Is it possible to clean migrate table? Which table allow this mapping? is there any hook function to achieve this functionality?

Comment: You are trying to merge content form 2 different websites, right?

Comment: I want to migrate content from www.a.com site to www.b.com site. Both are in drupal 7.

Comment: But www.b.com already has some content right? So you want to merge a and b content and have it all on b site? Just moving whole a site to b site is not working for you?

Comment: yes i have content in www.b.com, but some content are not get migrated. For example www.a.com have 1000 record and after migration www.b.com have only 600 record. How i can get those missing 400 records? I got stack over here.

Answer (score 2):

Can you Please use the Features module. Which is used to export and import the your content records and views everything.

https://www.drupal.org/project/features

Answer (score 0):

I've used both migrate and feeds (with feeds tamper) modules for Drupal 7 to 7 moves.  One of the most common reasons for the failure is missing dependencies - in particular either:

A) the content being imported is being imported with the same/original author uids associated with it

OR

B) the content type has node or entity reference fields on it. 
Then when you try to migrate/import it, it can't map the referenced node/entity if that node/entity doesn't exist yet on the new site.

---

For case A, you could just import/migrate the content reassigning the author; otherwise, you'd need to port over the author/user accounts first (and lookout for conflicts with existing user accounts already on site B)

For case B, you can create a separate GUID (such as legacydomain-guid-nid) and remap the reference fields using that separate GUID in lieu of the original node IDs.  It requires two "waves" of migration and import-

- first without any referenced field data, creating the nodes on the destination site
- second time updating those newly created nodes with the referenced field data, using the custom GUID as a mapping field.

---

Alternatively, if your recordset of nodes/content to move is not > 10,000 records, you can also use the node export and views bulk operations modules or node export and features/features extra modules.